# Как сделать чтоб css не применялся к какому-нибудь блоку внутри html?

Tags: html, css, framework

Например: есть html, к нему подключен framework (materialize, js и css) и плагин для отображения таблицы (tabulator, js и css). В html есть div, куда рендерится таблица с помощью плагина tabulator, со всякими select input фильтрами. Materialize вмешивается в эту таблицу и меняет стили input'ов таблицы. Как запретить Materializу обрабатывать этот div?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Ждём поддержку браузерами. Пока только Chrome 118+. https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_scope

```css
@scope (:root) to (.smth) {
  input {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<input> <input> <input>
<p><input> <input> <input></p>
<p class=smth><input> <input> <input></p>
<p><input> <input> <input></p>
<input> <input> <input></p>
```